# Loading 30 more Timeline High stock chart in jsp page?

Tags: highcharts

I implement the Timeline High stock chart to display large data points using data grouping.
Its working but want to load 30 more charts on single jsp page. Have for() loop in each iteration it will create one Timeline chart in servlet and send response to jsp page  ,  it displays the legened , tile but not chart , chart is coming only  when i click legend / zooming options..

Comment: First thing I would do is really think hard about the fact that you want 30 charts on a single page. Is it necessary? Can you combine charts so that a single chart has multiple series? Can you group these charts by topic and maybe have separate pages? If you really want to do this can you put up some sample code or better yet a jsFiddle with some charts to represent this issue?

Comment: Here You can see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrEDT/5/).This page is called from the for loop every-time , size of the for loop minimum 4 to 40.

Comment: If you are calling this exact code 4 to 40 times then it will try and make this exact chart 4 to 40 times. Is that what you mean? How are you calling the charts - that is the code we need. This jsfiddle example you posted does not show the issue or is representative of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If i load 40 charts it will load but browsers are freezed. if load 40 charts with large data points  - ex 60,000 points in each - what will happen ? . The condition is i do not use data grouping , navigator & rangeSelector.

Comment: The reason the browser "freezes" is because the javascript to render the charts is run on the client machine "in-browser". So, the rendering performance is limited by the client's horsepower. You really need to think on whether or not you really really want to load 40 dynamic charts on one single page. Why not group your charts by category? These look like disk drive monitor charts - so group the PCs by location and have one page for each?

Comment: Yes Minimum 17 chart should be load in single page .How to group highstock charts by category?

Comment: You would have to determine what the categories are. Are all the charts for the same "type"? Are they for the same location? I cannot answer that for you. Is it necessary to load interactive charts? You can turn off lots of the interaction to save resources. Also, if these are static charts you can just render image files of the charts and display them.

Comment: But i need dynamic charts.